# Is there a fast and easy way to calculate high powers mentally, e.g. $ 67^{81} $?

Tags: arithmetic

I have done research into vedic mathematics and I was wondering if it's possible that a faster method exists than the one I already know which involves Pascal's triangle.

Comment: How *fast* and *easy* do you want your method to be? $67^{81}$ has $148$ digits and regardless of which method you use, (unless you use a computer) it will be very *slow* and *painful*.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments, I'm assuming you don't actually need all the digits, just an approximation. For this you can use $x^y = 10^{y \log_{10} x }$, and then break down $x$ to it's nearest power of ten - this will work well when $x$ is large. In your example:
$$67^{81}=10^{81 \log_{10} 67}$$
$$\log_{10} 67=\log_{10} (0.67\times100)=2+\log_{10} (0.67) =2+\frac{\ln 0.67}{\ln 10}$$
Using the Taylor series, you can calculate:
$$\ln 0.67=\ln(1-0.33)\approx-0.33-\frac{0.33^2}{2}-\frac{0.33^3}{3}\approx-0.396$$
And now using $\ln 10\approx 2.3$, we have: 
$$81\log_{10} 67 \approx 148$$
Giving you $10^{148}$, which is really close to the correct $\approx8.2\times 10^{147}$.